# IE9- z-index/overflow issue?

Tags: internet-explorer, z-index, css

I'm currently working on this site: http://goo.gl/uRGsh

The problem i'm having is that in IE9- the logo in the menu seems to get cut off. Or that is what i think happens, at least. When testing in IE10 dev tools (in ie9 mode) i'm getting a lot of flickering when hovering over different menu items, and the submenu covers the under part of the logotype. When testing on browserlab, which runs virtual machines or something, the logo is simply cut off (only the part within the menu is visible).

Screenshot of IE8:

[image: Screenshot of IE8]

I've spent hours trying to fix this. The wrappers around the logo has `overflow: visible;`, so that *should* not be the reason. The top menubar also has a higher z-index than the submenu, so the submenu should not be overlapping the logo. The logo is placed within the top menubar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

IE9 and Chrome look the same for me on my machine.

Did you try deleting history and cache and all that stuff?

When using a z-index a position must also be stated. Doesn't appear to be a position on the logo.

EDITS

I just cannot replicate this error you show in your snapshot. Tried IE8 and Chrome on XP and IE9 on W7 on two different machines.

Maybe something with your VM, but you did say you just checked on another computer.?

I did now see the position on .logotype. It has z-index: 7 when listed with:

```
.header-section .full-menu .logotype
```

and the menu-container is z-index:6 when listed with

```
.header-section .menu-container
```

I don't think it is a z-index thing. I noticed the above is overflow: visible. Maybe it should be hidden.

If that is not it I would try applying z-index:6 or less (with a position:relative too) to the various

```
.header-section .menu-container ul
```

and

```
.header-section .menu-container li
```

and

```
.header-section .menu-container li a
```

Maybe something with .logo-placeholder. There is no position or z-index on that. I cant determine what it is for.

Kind of guessing here. Hard to see when I can't replicate the issue.

Comment: I have indeed cleaned my history/cache etc. I'll check on another computer in a sec. The logo is relatively positioned. The image is wrapped in an `<a>` tag with a class of `.logotype`. Can you open the dev tools and check the site in IE8 mode?

Comment: Just checked on IE9 on a teammates computer and the submenu does indeed cover the logo when you hover the menu items.

Comment: I just cannot replicate this error you show in your snapshot. Tried IE8 and Chrome on XP and IE9 on W7 on two different machines.

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to reply but i did a little re-writing and got it working. The logotype was positioned inside the `.menu-container` before, i moved it outside and positioned it absolutely. Then i gave the menu's some padding, and it seems to work great!

Comment: @qwerty's answer had the key for me - if you've got something absolutely positioned inside your container the container wont take the height of that element into account (hence the element gets cut off or hidden)